# How to execute two if conditions in android

Tags: android, if-statement

I want to execute two if conditions either first if condition or second if condition based on my requirement.

Now below code if it executing second if condition everytime

switch (specilaity_name) {
case "Cardiac":
linearspeclist.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_border_theme);
speclialistimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);
specialization.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
break;
case "Urology":
linearspeclist.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_border_theme);
speclialistimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_urology__1___1_);
specialization.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
break;
case "Gynaecology":
linearspeclist.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_border_theme);
speclialistimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_group_2105);
specialization.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
break;
}

Comment: try by removing "else" but keep the "if" after "else

Comment: Dude! Your code is messed up. This is not how you should write it.

Answer (score 0):

Well. You're using nested if else in the else part of outer if for each block of code.
If only code in second structure is working, then that's the only condition which holds true during execution of your App.

Answer (score 0):

String specialityName = specilaity_name.toUpperCase();

```
switch (specialityName) {
case "CARDIAC":  
linearspeclist.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_border_theme);
speclialistimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);
specialization.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);     
break;
case "UROLOGY":  
// add code for urology  
break;
case "GYNAECOLOGY":        
// add code for Gynaecology  
break;
default:   
break;
}
```

}

Comment: `make it simple switch` how ? if someone is completely new to them this isn't obvious and your answer won't be really useful, just give an example of how it's done

Comment: String specialityName = specilaity_name.toUpperCase();
    switch (specialityName) {
      case "CARDIAC":  
 linearspeclist.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_border_theme);
 speclialistimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);
 specialization.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);     
        break;

      case "UROLOGY":  
 // add code for urology  
        break;
      
      case "GYNAECOLOGY":        
 // add code for Gynaecology  
        break;
      default:   
        break;
    }
  }

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65791853/edit) your question to include these changes

Comment: switch condition how to make transparent background

Comment: <your view>.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Answer (score 0):

```
if(specilaity_name.equalsIgnoreCase("Cardiac")){
                        linearspeclist.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_border_theme);
                        speclialistimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);
                        specialization.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }else if(specilaity_name.equalsIgnoreCase("Urology")) {
                            linearspeclist.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_border_white);
                        speclialistimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_urology__1_);
                        specialization.setTextColor(Color.rgb(73,179,206));
                        }else {
                            linearspeclist.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_border_white);
                            speclialistimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_group_2105);
                            specialization.setTextColor(Color.rgb(73, 179, 206));
                        }
```

Comment: Second if condition also want to execute

Comment: I am confusing about the second condition

Comment: Why are you confusing you should give it a try

Comment: your if condition not satisfying my creteria

Comment: I have Three  speciality_names i.e Cardic,urology and Gyn.if user presses Cardic remaing two should be default only first one should activite.

Comment: if user select cardiac on the if condition with cadiac will activate... if user is select urology then the else if condition with urology will activate... and user not select cardiology or urology then ofcourse it should be gyn so the last condition will apply

Comment: yes.But on click on cardiac I am changing bg color and icons also in the same way

Comment: otherwise show me your activity and full code so that i can see and better understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227540/discussion-between-jyothi-sri-and-usama-altaf).